# Cannot access Apache Airflow web UI when enabling authenticate = True

Tags: airflow

I have apache airflow running perfectly fine with default settings, when I set     authenticate = False  in the the airflow.cfg file

But I am unable to access the Web UI when i set authenticate = True
I am following the instructions from the website 
https://incubator-airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html

I am using Version : 1.10.1

When i try to access web ui, I get the message
This site can’t be reached  or too many redirects

## airflow.cfg  file

[webserver]

```
authenticate = True
auth_backend = airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth
```

## Create my user with python

```
import airflow
from airflow import models, settings
from airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth import PasswordUser
user = PasswordUser(models.User())
user.username = 'my.user'
user.email = 'my.user@company.com'
user.password = 'password'
session = settings.Session()
session.add(user)
session.commit()
session.close()
exit()
```

## restart airflow

Comment: Can you check if there is a duplicate setting for  `auth_backend` in `[webserver]`. If so, remove it

Comment: I tried removing any duplicates settings, and re initialize the db. but still have the same issue.   I downgraded to Airflow Version 1.9.0. and it works fine now.

Comment: I agree with @shawn. With Airflow 2.0.1, the command has been updated to airflow users create -r Admin -u admin -e admin@example.com -f admin -l user -p test

Answer (score 2):

I've tried the way same as yours to create airflow user, it couldn't work.
Simply you can use command like this `airflow create_user -r Admin -u admin -e admin@example.com -f admin -l user -p test` in airflow webserver shell.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

Activate you airflow python environment and start `python` shell.
Then with the help of these commands you can easily set a new user in airflow.

```
>>> import airflow
>>> from airflow import models, settings
>>> from airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth import PasswordUser
>>> user = PasswordUser(models.User())
>>> user.username = 'new_user_name'
>>> user.email = 'new_user_email@example.com'
>>> user.password = 'set_the_password'
>>> session = settings.Session()
>>> session.add(user)
>>> session.commit()
>>> session.close()
>>> exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error after debugging for 3 hours I found that I had a tiny mistake, It is because while you creating users for airflow you didn't specified role. I don't know what is the default role. But if the Default role is **Public** (Available roles are Admin, User, Viewer, Public, and Op) then even after successful login you redirect to the homepage, but **Public** role doesn't have permission to view dags. So if you see the webserver log you see a warning message like cannot **index on airflow**. So I would recommend you to create a user with respective requirements.
For example use CLI for creating user of airflow.

`$ airflow create_user -h` shows command options, and then set params according to them.

`$ airflow create_user -r Viewer -u <username> -p <login_password whatever you want> -f <first name> -l <last_name> -e <email_id>`

Hope that works for you, it was working for me. ps: I'm using google_auth as backend.

Answer (score 0):

`create_user` seems to be deprecated, so please use this:

```
airflow users create --username admin --role Admin --email A@B.com --firstname A --lastname B
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple mistake that can cost your time, `check the permissions of your directories and files` e.g I was using a systemd daemon file to run webserver and scheduler.
My mistake was to set `User=root` while everything in airflow directory and files belonged to user `abc` so;

```
[Unit]
Description=Airflow Web Server

[Service]
User=abc
Type=simple
Environment="PATH=/home/abc/venv_airflow/bin"
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'cd /home/abc/ && source venv_airflow/bin/activate && airflow db init && airflow webserver --port 8080'
Restart=always
RestartSec=5s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```